# Is it possible that $X>\operatorname E[X]$ for a random variable $X$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space and $X\in\mathcal L^1(\operatorname P)$. I'm wondering whether or not we can prove that $\exists\omega\in\Omega$ with $$X(\omega)\le\operatorname E[X]\;.\tag 1$$ Assuming that $X>\operatorname E[X]$ doesn't immediately (by taking the expectation) yield a contradiction, while the statement itself seems to be trivially true. So, *can* we show $(1)$ and if so, *how*?

Comment: Could you clarify why you would assume that $X>\operatorname E[X]$ "doesn't immediately yield a contradiction"?

Comment: @user46944 You're wrong, that isn't what I'd in mind. What I meant is that $X>\operatorname E[X]$ only yields that $$\operatorname E[X]\ge\operatorname E\left[\operatorname E[X]\right]=\operatorname E[X]$$ (by monotonicity of expectation) and that's (of course) no contradiction.

Comment: @user46944 Are you *sure* this is only true for non-negative r.v.'s? It looks to me that $X< Y$ a.s. does imply $\mathbb{E}[X] \leq \mathbb{E}[Y]$ (provided both r.v.'s have a well-defined expectation).

Comment: @ClementC. You're right.  I was mixing up properties.  We only have "$E[X] = 0 \implies X = 0$ a.s." if $X$ is nonnegative.  For some reason, I applied that assumption from the mentioned unrelated property to the monotonicity property, which is wrong.

Comment: @user46944 ??? Can you give us an example showing that non-negativity is required? (Hint: No. If $f>g$ it's easy to show that $\int f>\int g$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I addressed my mistake 42 seconds ago.

Comment: @user46944 No worries :) (a good way to remember is that if you believe $f\geq 0$ implies $\int f\geq 0$, then you can just get all you want from $f-g$)

Comment: @ClementC. But $f\ge 0$ *does* imply $\int f\ge 0$.

Comment: Yes, it does. ${}{}$

Comment: @ClementC. Then I don't understand why you state "if you *believe* ...".

Comment: @0xbadf00d I should maybe have said "If you already are convinced." The point of my comment is that one can easily (re)prove the monotonicity property from the non-negativity one, in one line: which makes it easier to remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $X\in L^1$ satisfies $X > \mathbb{E}[X]$ a.s. In particular, there exists $a> \mathbb{E}[X]$ such that $p\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \mathbb{P}\{X \geq a\} > 0$.

Then $$\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}[X] &\geq a\cdot \mathbb{P}\{X \geq a\} + \mathbb{E}[X]\cdot \mathbb{P}\{X < a\} = a\cdot p + \mathbb{E}[X]\cdot (1-p) \\
&= \mathbb{E}[X]+\underbrace{(a-\mathbb{E}[X])}_{>0}\cdot p > \mathbb{E}[X]
\end{align}$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why does it follow that $\Bbb E[X; X<a]\ge\Bbb E[X]\cdot\Bbb P[X<a]$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins  I do not understand the notation you use on the LHS. What I relied on is that, writing $\alpha = \mathbb{E}[X]$, assuming $X \geq \alpha$ a.s. implies $$\mathbb{E}[X] \geq \beta\cdot \mathbb{P}\{X \geq \beta\} + \alpha\cdot \mathbb{P}\{X < \beta\}$$ for all $\beta\geq \alpha$. (Since $\mathbb{P}\{X \geq \alpha\} = 1$ *by assumption*.)

Comment: My bad...nevermind.  ($\Bbb E[X; X<a]$ is just $\Bbb E[X1_{\{X<a\}}]$.)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that notation. Thanks!

Comment: Let me try to understand why we need to have some $\alpha$ with the stated properties. I assume your reasoning is that $$\left\{X>\operatorname E[X]\right\}=\bigcup_{\alpha>\operatorname E[X]}\left\{X\ge\alpha\right\}\tag 1$$ and that if $\operatorname P[X\ge\alpha]$ would be $0$ for all $\alpha>\operatorname E[X]$, then $$\operatorname P\left[X>\operatorname E[X]\right]\le\sum_{\alpha>\operatorname E[X]}\operatorname P[X\ge\alpha]=0\tag 2$$ by the $\sigma$-subadditivity of the measure $\operatorname P$, right?

Comment: **But** this only works if the union/sum in $(2)$/$(3)$ is countable. So, you should state $\alpha\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I guess so, yes, to hint towards the argument of existence -- this may help clarify the implicit steps: but the statement in my answer does not require this (i.e.: it is true as now; would perhaps be clearer if it said "there exists a rational $a$"; but would also still be true if it said "there exists an irrational $a$," even though there would be absolutely no reason to write this except for screwing with the mind of any reader).

Comment: That is, to prove there exists some $a>\mathbb{E}[X]$ may require to consider only rationals, for countability reasons; but once such a (rational) is found, well... there will be an irrational strictly between it and $\mathbb{E}[X]$ as well.  Note that (to avoid confusion for potential readers) what you call $\alpha$ is the $a$ in my answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Your statement "there exists $a$ ..." is true and we don't need to confuse anyone by details in this spep. And yes, I've confused $a$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: Well, it's always better to have the details somewhere -- I did sweep this step under the rug in my answer.

Comment: I absolutely don't understand your first inequality and the inequality in your first comment. Shouldn't we have $$\operatorname E[X]=\left(\operatorname P[X<\beta]+\operatorname P[X\ge\beta]\right)\operatorname E[X]\le\operatorname P[X<\beta]\operatorname E[X]+\operatorname P[X\ge\beta]\beta$$ for all $\beta\ge\operatorname E[X]$?

Comment: Let $\beta > \alpha$, and suppose that $X \geq \alpha$ a.s. Then we can write $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{[\beta, \infty)} x\mathbb{P}\{X\in dx\}+\int_{[\alpha, \beta)} x\mathbb{P}\{X\in dx\}+\int_{(-\infty, \alpha)} x\mathbb{P}\{X\in dx\}.$$ The last integral is $0$ by assumption, so we are left with $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{[\beta, \infty)} x\mathbb{P}\{X\in dx\}+\int_{[\alpha, \beta)} x\mathbb{P}\{X\in dx\}
\geq \beta \int_{[\beta, \infty)} \mathbb{P}\{X\in dx\} + \alpha \int_{[\alpha, \beta)} \mathbb{P}\{X\in dx\}  = \beta\mathbb{P}\{X\geq \beta\} + \alpha   \mathbb{P}\{X\in[\alpha, \beta)\}$$

Comment: Since $\mathbb{P}\{X\in[\alpha, \beta)\} = \mathbb{P}\{X\in(-\infty, \beta)\}$ because $X\geq \alpha$ a.s., this becomes finally  $$\mathbb{E}[X] \geq \beta\cdot \mathbb{P}\{X\geq \beta\} + \alpha\cdot  \mathbb{P}\{X < \beta\}.$$ @0xbadf00d

Comment: But you agree to me that my inequality is true, too, do you? If both inequalities hold, we would have equality in fact. What am I missing?

Comment: You're not missing anything. Combing the two inequalities gives, for $p=\mathbb{P}\{ X \geq \beta \}$, that $$
\beta\cdot p + \mathbb{E}[X] (1-p) \geq \beta \cdot p + \alpha\cdot (1-p)
$$
for any $\beta > \geq \mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\alpha$ such that $X\geq \alpha$ a.s., with strict inequality if $p > 0$. Equivalently, 
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] (1-p) \geq \alpha\cdot (1-p)
$$
with strict inequality if $p>0$. Now, what this final inequality says is that if $\alpha  \geq \mathbb{E}[X]$, then we must have either ($p=0$ and $\alpha=\mathbb{E}[X]$), or $p=1$.

Comment: That is, there is no contradiction: there exist some settings of $\alpha,p$ that make the two inequalities compatible. And it turns out that, fortunately, the rest of the proof shows that one must be in one of these situations (namely, the question and the answer argue that, assuming $\alpha = \mathbb{E}[X]$, we cannot have $p>0$).